# C# Input string was not in a correct format. Conversion issue on server not in local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, jcrop

I am croppping the image and save. On btnsave_click I am converting the hiddenfield value to decimal. There is no error on local machine but when published to server it gives below error.

**Detailed exception on server**:

### *Input string was not in a correct format.*

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +10726387    System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) +172
>   System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value) +68
>   IngredientMatcher.Pages.ImageCropPopup.btnsave_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +104
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9552602
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

**Code :**:

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ImageName = ViewState["ImageName"].ToString();
    int www = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(W.Value)));
    int hhh = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(H.Value)));
    int xxx = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(X.Value)));
    int yyy = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Y.Value)));
    int w = (www == 0) ? 0 : www;
    int h = (hhh == 0) ? 0 : hhh;
    int x = (xxx == 0) ? 0 : xxx;
    int y = (yyy == 0) ? 0 : yyy;

    byte[] CropImage = Crop(Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\" + upPath + ImageName, w, h, x, y);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length))
    {
        ms.Write(CropImage, 0, CropImage.Length);
        using (SD.Image CroppedImage = SD.Image.FromStream(ms, true))
        {
            string SaveTo = Server.MapPath("") + "\\" + CropPath + "crop" + ImageName;

            CroppedImage.Save(SaveTo, CroppedImage.RawFormat);
            imgCropped.BorderWidth = 1;
            imgCropped.ImageUrl = CropPath + "crop" + ImageName;
        }
    }
    string CroppedImg = "crop" + ViewState["ImageName"].ToString();

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "OpenPopUp", "javascript:SaveAndClose('" + CroppedImg + "');", true);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The exception points to Convert.ToDecimal, thus the problem is in the W,H,X,Y values. Probably one of them is an empty string and Convert.ToDecimal doesn't like it

Comment: Honestly the best solution is going to be to dump some debugging in there, possibly write or log the values of WHXY and that'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in the culture used to convert the decimal. Some cultures use 0,01 and some use 0.01. therein lies the problem.

You could use the invariant culture (always 0.01 as input) for example:

```
int www = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(W.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
int hhh = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(H.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
int xxx = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(X.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
int yyy = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(Y.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

Or you could use your culture, just replace `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL")` where the constructor string is replaced with your culture.

Comment: Yes, that could work well but what are W,H,X,Y? If there is the possibility that these `Value` contains an empty string the code will throw again the exception

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure that the value converted are effectively numbers and not empty strings before trying to execute any conversion operation. To obtain this resultthe best approach is through the Decimal.TryParse method that checks if you have really a valid decimal number for your culture and then execute the conversions and math operations on the value

```
decimal dw;
decimal dh;
decimal dx;
decimal dy;

int www = 0;
int hhh = 0;
int xxx = 0;
int yyy = 0;

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");  // Here your specific culture

if(decimal.TryParse(W.Value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out dw))
    www = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(dw));
if(decimal.TryParse(W.Value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out dh))
    hhh = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(dh));
if(decimal.TryParse(W.Value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out dx))
    xxx = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(dx));
if(decimal.TryParse(W.Value, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, out dy))
    yyy = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(dy));
```

Comment: I have taken the hiddenfield default value as 0. SO there is no chance of empty. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

In the `web.config`, in `system.web` section add this, change culture to local region:

```
<globalization
   fileEncoding="utf-8"
   requestEncoding="utf-8"
   responseEncoding="utf-8"
   culture="es-PA"
   uiCulture="de-DE"
/>
```